Error by using xacro:if in a xml code
I have writen the fllowing code for a gazebo simulation in ROS2. I am using Visual Studio Code
<!-- Wheels-->
<gazebo reference="wehl_right_link">
    <mu1>100000000000000.0</mu1>
    <mu2>100000000000000.0</mu2>
    <kp>1000000000000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="wehl_left_link">
    <mu1>100000000000000.0</mu1>
    <mu2>100000000000000.0</mu2>
    <kp>1000000000000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
</gazebo>

<!-- Caster Wheels-->
<gazebo reference="caster_front_link">
    <mu1>0.1</mu1>
    <mu2>0.1</mu2>
    <kp>1000000.0</kp>
    <kd>100.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="caster_rear_link">
    <mu1>0.1</mu1>
    <mu2>0.1</mu2>
    <kp>1000000.0</kp>
    <kd>100.0</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
</gazebo>

<gazebo>
   <xacro:if value="$(arg is_ignition)">
        <plugin filename="ign_ros2_control-system" name_"ign_ros2-control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin">
            <parameters></parameters>
        </plugin>
   </xacro:if>


   <xacro:unless value="$(arg is_ignition)">
        <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system" name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
            <parameters></parameters>
        </plugin>
   </xacro:unless>
</gazebo>

Visual Studio Code don't accept Xacro:if. I always get the error:The prefix "xacro" for "xacro:if" is not bound. xml(ElementPrefixUnbound)strong text

When using xacro elements like xacro:if and xacro:unless you have to provide a xacro declaration of it.
Add
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="name_of_your_robot">

at the top of your file and also add a close mark at the bottom
</robot>

This should help resolve your issue.
